# Is there an AI / ML service that is generally used after STT?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am successfully done with the speech to text conversion program and the results show a usual **`80-90 %`** confidence in the transcript.

Now is there a way (a service) that can be used (or usually used) to improve the confidence in the transcript?

**For example:**
I want to search a name from the directory

```
.
.
Sunil Chauhan
Sunit Chavan
Sumit Chawhan
.
.
```

All the above three names are valid (as in they exist). But `Sunit` is less common than `Sunil` or `Sumit`, and all of them have an almost similar surname.

We can understand the difference in human speech but how to differentiate the text response from Google speech recognition which gives the most common `Sunil/Sumit` with most common `Chauhan` for `Sunit Chavan`.

Is there an available AI or ML service which can be used in such cases?

Comment: I am not aware of an existing solution to do this, it can be done by writing a custom function, but the exact function will depend on thee type of output you get out of your neural net, also I won't recommend doing that unless absolutely necessary as it will require either manual rules for every word or skewing the output of your model

Comment: @anand_v.singh Yes I agree, writing manual function and providing the sample database is undeniable here. But do there exist **some cloud platform service already being used** in industrial context which might solve this. Considering that the least (correct) transcript do not get ignored. **Or** is there **an algorithm** which can be looked into?

Comment: Pretty sure they don't sorry, I also asked a few friends in the field and they all said the same, they also don't know if one exists and not to try it as well, for same reasons that I gave, sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: @anand_v.singh Hey that's fine. I am here to learn so I am open to all suggestions, Even if it is negative. So cheers!

Comment: Quick question, you are now unable to predict Sunit because it's uncommon, or are you predicting Sunit more than you would like to?

Comment: It predicts either `Sunil` or `Sumit` which are more common than `Sunit` unless the name is specifically said with giving emphasis on each syllable (which we generally don't do).

Comment: Oh this, you can easily solve by augmenting cases of Sunit and modulate the sound signal a bit, then train on your data, that should solve it, try this and you might get some interesting Ideas https://medium.com/@alibugra/audio-data-augmentation-f26d716eee66

Comment: I thought your problem was you were predicting too many times `Sunit` and wanted to suppress that a bit since it's uncommon, hence me recommending you not to do that